# What is "Hadozee wavedashing"?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits

When talking about the recently released Spelljammer supplement ([*Spelljammer: Adventures in Space*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/spelljammer)), some people mention "Hadozee wavedashing". What is that?

Answer (score 21):

The [Hadozee](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/1121697-hadozee) has a [racial trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/1121697-hadozee#HadozeeTraits) called Glide, which allows them to move 5 feet horizontally (without expending any of their movement) whenever they fall 1 foot vertically. A Hadozee can jump vertically, then glide as they fall back down. Since 1 foot of jumping costs 1 foot of movement, this effectively allows a Hadozee to multiply their speed by 5 by repeatedly jumping and then gliding.

This technique has been nicknamed "Wavedashing" by the community, referencing the "[wavedash](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Wavedash)" technique from the *Super Smash Bros.* series of games in which you essentially double jump into the ground so you slide along the floor. The Hadozee technique is obviously quite different, but the name stuck.

Comment: By teleporting straight up this turns misty step into a very effective escape!

Comment: @SeriousBri Nice, you invented mist dashing! Or wave misting?  Why stop there, dimension door 500ft straight up and you can glide 2500ft!

Comment: Though it is still questionable if you are not limited by your normal movement speed, so if you have a movement speed of 30ft you can only jump + glide for a total of 30ft

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that this isn’t a new ability, the Simic Hybrid from *Guildmaster’s Guide to Ravnica* has the same feature with two feet instead of five feet.

Comment: I think "essentially double jump" could be spelled out a bit more considering the games have an *actual* double jump and it is not used for wave dashing. Probably just copy the page you've linked to directly: "performed by air dodging diagonally into the ground, causing the character to slide a short distance"

Comment: It's not limited by your speed. Unlike the simic hybrid, the hadozee rule text specifically addresses that question: "You can move up to 5 feet horizontally for every 1 foot you descend in the air, *at no movement cost to you*."

Comment: Note this feature has been changed in the [SJA-Errata](https://media.wizards.com/2022/dnd/downloads/SJA-Errata.pdf) and no longer works since it is now limited by your speed and requires at least a 10 foot fall.